# ENSIME not finding the correct project definition

Tags: scala, ensime

I'm using an Emacs 24 snapshot on Ubuntu 12.04 with Scala 2.9.2 and `ensime_2.9.2-RC1-0.9.3.RC4`.

Basically I did the same thing as described in https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/ensime/HvvvFr5gSwg

- I generate .ensime file using sbt `ensime generate`.
- I start ENSIME on Emacs with `M-x ensime`.
- It parses all libraries and so on correctly (auto-complete works properly etc.)

However when I try to start the SBT console within Emacs using `C-c C-v s`, it displays the following error:

`[info] Loading project definition from /home/ximyu/.sbt/plugins`

`[info] Updating {file:/home/ximyu/.sbt/plugins/}default-86f483...`

`[error] a module is not authorized to depend on itself: default#default-86f483;0.0`

`[error] {file:/home/ximyu/.sbt/plugins/}default-86f483/*:update:`
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: a module is not authorized to depend on itself: default#default-86f483;0.0`

Obviously ENSIME is looking at the wrong directory for project definition. Instead of looking at my project directory it is actually looking at `~/.sbt`.  Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I just started with ensime, so I don't really know why this is the case either. Also, my knowlegde on scala & ensime is very limited, so this is only a work-around to something that might be more obvious.

Anyway, this is the problematic ensime function:

```
(defun ensime-sbt-project-dir-p (path)
  "Is path an sbt project?"
  (or (not (null (directory-files path nil "\\.sbt$")))
      (file-exists-p (concat path "/project/Build.scala" ))
      (file-exists-p (concat path "/project/boot" ))
      (file-exists-p (concat path "/project/build.properties" ))))
```

Basically ensime will use above function to search for a folder above the buffer where you hit C-c C-v s to determine the root project folder. As such, an **easy fix** is to simply **add** a (empty) *.sbt* folder into the folder that contains your .ensime project description.

Comment: This is actually documented in `C-h f sbt:find-root`:

What worked for me was creating a `build.properties` file my project's `project` dir.